# Show/Hide element on click

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I'm trying to toggle an element to show/hide when I click on the title. So far I have this approach

```
<div class="parent" (click)="status=!status" [ngClass]="status ? 'hide' : 'display'">
   <div class="child">
     <p>Info to show or hide</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

On CSS file I have this

```
.hide .child {
  display: none;
}
```

This works fine for what I need when I have one element. But I want to display several of this items with an *ngFor. When I do that, then variable `status` is shared and clicking on any of the other elements will toggle all of them. Since the creation of elements is dynamic, is there any way to limit the scope of `status` variable to just that element? Or is there a better approach to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In yours `component.ts` file, add property `status` in each array `element` and assign `true` to `element.status`.

Then loop over the `element`s of array using `ngFor` and use `element.status` to toggle specefic `element` as below in your `component.html` file:

```
<div *ngFor="let element of myArray" class="parent" (click)="element.status=!element.status" [ngClass]="element.status ? 'hide' : 'display'">
    <div class="child">
        <p>Info to show or hide</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

YOu need a `status` variable in each object

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items" class="parent" (click)="item.status=!item.status" [ngClass]="item.status ? 'hide' : 'display'">
   <div class="child">
     <p>Info to show or hide</p>
   </div>
</div>
```